# Two way databinding with collection on Xamarin.Android/Android

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I have a UI with some EditTexts in it and this set of edittexts can repeat number of times (not too much but 3 - 10 times max) based on the number of items in the list.

User can edit/modify/delete the item or edit the value of the edit texts. Currently I am doing this manually with "AddView/RemoveView", manually handling the states etc, however it is a lot of work as I have many scenarios like this.

We have a web app with the very same functionalities and we are using AngularJS to deal with all these, which, as you know is amazingly easy.

is there any closer way to bind the axml/xml view with a collection (may be an Observable collection and at least from the code behind) that will take care of collection changes as well as the individual field changes without me doing all this manually. In some scenarios I have to display images as well.

Also, I tried using a ListView, however it doesn't work as I would expect it to work.

Comment: If you let me know the reason for the negative vote I can edit & fix that. I tried my level best to concise and express the problem statement, so that any one who is aware of data binding can understand the question. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any closer way to bind the axml/xml view with a collection (may be an Observable collection and at least from the code behind) that will take care of collection changes as well as the individual field changes without me doing all this manually.

The answer is no, there isn't. Android's views have to be bound to certain context/activity when they are created. They can't be isolated, so add/remove the `EditText`s have to be implemented by yourself.

Currently, the closest way to your requirement is to create an `ObservableCollection` and listen for the `CollectionChanged` event and when `CollectionChanged` add/remove the view in your container:

```
[Activity(Label = "Demo", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Button btnAdd;
    ObservableCollection<View> oc;
    LinearLayout container;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.Click += BtnAdd_Click;
        GenerateET(Resource.Id.container, this, 3);
    }

    private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        et.Text = "test";
        et.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        oc.Add(et);
    }

    public void GenerateET(int resId, Activity activity,int num)
    {
        //create an observable collection
        oc = new ObservableCollection<View>();
        container = activity.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(resId);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            EditText et = new EditText(activity);
            et.Text = "test";
            et.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            container.AddView(et);
            oc.Add(et);
        }

        oc.CollectionChanged += Oc_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Oc_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
            {
                //add the view manually
                container.AddView((View)e.NewItems[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </LinearLayout>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add EditText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nice! a little more easier way than I have already, done. Much appreciated!